# A question on the differential of the Gauss map

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $S$ be a orientable, regular surface, locally parametrized by $(U, F, V)$.

Let $N$ be the Gauss map. The Weingarten map is defined with a point $p$ in $U$ as $W_p: T_pS \rightarrow T_pS$ , $X\mapsto -dN_p(X)=\dfrac{d}{dt}(N\circ \alpha)|_{t=0}$, where $\alpha$ is a smooth curve that $\alpha(0)=p, \alpha'(0)=X$.  .

If now, I want to compute the coefficient of the matrix for the second fundamental form w.r.t the basis $(\delta F/\delta x, \delta F/\delta y)$, I have to know what is $-dN_p(\delta F/\delta x)$, so I have to find the curve that tangent to $\delta F/\delta x$ like $\alpha$ above.

So what is that curve?

Answer (score 0):

The result depends only on $\alpha^\prime(0)$, i.e. on the tangent vector in that point. You are free to choose any ($C^1$) curve through that point with that tangent vector in that point. For the case you are interested in you can just look at the curve $t\mapsto F(t,0)$, assuming your coordinate map is centered at the origin and $x$ corresponds to the first variable.

Comment: Could you please explain more clearly? From your construction, I do not see that $c'(0)= \delta F/\delta x$

Comment: What is your $\delta F/\delta x$? I'm not familiar with thi notation, but I'd assume it is just the tangential of $F$ in direction $x$, $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}$. Then calculate, using the chain rule, $\frac{d}{dt}F(t,0) |_{t=0} = \frac{\delta F}{\delta x}(0,0)\frac{dx}{dt}$. The last factor in the last term is just $=1$.